# Ignore complete subdomain from https in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to achieve the following thing in my HTACCESS. 
I have some lines to force all connections over HTTPS://.

I want to *exclude* specific subdomains because I don't have SSL on them.

```
## HTTPS FORCE & NO WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

## Exclude list
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/SUBDOMAIN/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The **problem** here is, it works only for the subdomain and no deeper level files.

- SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com is now without HTTPS
- SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com/image.png is still forced over HTTPS

What do I have to add to the exluding lines to make sure it's ignoring the complete subdomain with all of it's content?

Answer (score 0):

The redirects are probably cached by your browser. Clear your cache or use another browser, then try again.